# Update with select not working as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables

First Table

```
create table ApprovedLeave(
Username varchar(100),
FromDate date,
ToDate date,
type varchar(100),
address varchar(1000),
contactNo varchar(20),
NoofWorkingDays int,
);
```

Second Table

```
create table EMPLOYEE(
FName varchar(100),
LName varchar(200),
Username varchar(100),
NoOfDaysRemaining int,
constraint emp1 primary key(Username));
```

Once the leave is approved, I want to update with this logic:

**NoOfDaysRemaining = NoOfDaysRemaining- NoofWorkingDays**

So far what I have doesn't perform the above operation.

```
   create Procedure UpdateNoOfDays2 
   AS
BEGIN  
update le
    set NoOfDaysRemaining = al.sum_NoofWorkingDays
    from EMPLOYEE le join
         (select UserName, sum(NoofWorkingDays) as sum_NoofWorkingDays
          from ApprovedLeave
          group by UserName
         ) al
         on le.UserName = al.UserName
         End
```

How can I add in this logic?

Comment: Waht is the question?

Comment: Use `LIKE`, not `=` to compare varchars?

Comment: This has nothing to do with C# or ASP .NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is missing a question, but based on this:

> NoOfDaysRemaining = NoOfDaysRemaining- NoofWorkingDays

Are you wanting this?
`SET NoOfDaysRemaining = NoOfDaysRemaining - al.sum_NoofWorkingDays`

```
UPDATE le
SET    NoOfDaysRemaining = NoOfDaysRemaining - al.sum_NoofWorkingDays
FROM   EMPLOYEE le 
INNER JOIN
         (SELECT   UserName, sum(NoofWorkingDays) as sum_NoofWorkingDays
          FROM     ApprovedLeave
          GROUP BY UserName
         ) al ON le.UserName = al.UserName
```

Comment: @Omesh No problem - also I edited your question to clarify what you were asking.  Make sure you explicitly type a question in the future.  Your posts will be better received and it makes understanding the problem easier. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.